# MYSQL: Update one table with a primary generated by insert on another

Tags: mysql, jdbctemplate

Is there a way to update a column on one table with the primary key generated by an insert on a different table in one transaction?

The following code example *does not work*, but perhaps illustrates what I am trying to do in MySql:

```
UPDATE orders SET address_id = (INSERT INTO addresses() values())
WHERE order_id = 666
```

I'm trying to do this in the context of a jdbcTemplate update.

Comment: Why you wouldn't do INSERT INTO first than use LAST_INSERT_ID to UPDATE table...

Comment: I could but I'm trying to get 'er done in one statement

Comment: I'm not that smart (not even close) :D Hope you'll find someone to solve that... GL

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function or procedure and execute the statements in sequence.

See following EXAMPLE:

```
delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE insert_update_address (PARAMETERS)
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO adresses(COLUMNS) values(PARAMETERS);
 UPDATE orders SET address_id = LAST_INSERT_ID()
 WHERE order_id = Parameter1;
END//

delimiter ;
```

And call it with:

```
CALL insert_update_address(PARAMS);
```

For more information see:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: OK thanks: so just using pure SQL it sounds like you're saying what I'm asking is not possible, right?

Comment: @IcedDante Not in one statement yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use transactions with JDBCTemplates. That way you can do the insert followed by the update. Check this [tutorial](http://www.journaldev.com/2603/spring-transaction-management-example-with-jdbc).